# How do you tighten a Hope seat post quick release?

Tags: seatpost, quick-release

I have a couple of these Hope seat post quick release, but I realised I don't know how to tighten it. I am referring to the adjustment on the bolt (not the qr lever).

[image: Hope brand seat-post clamp]

Comment: Pull the locking lever out, then twist the nut on the other side.  Do a little at a time, testing by closing the lever after each iteration to see if it's tight enough.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: That's an answer! I'd just add: In the exact same way as QR lever should be correctly closed.

Comment: @Carel - You're welcome to answer it -- I'm too lazy to.

Comment: Hopefully you guys don't feel me answering it is wrong given that you did basically put the answer as a comment. I elaborated on purpose, coz why not...

Comment: what possibly confused me about this, is that there is no allen bolt to tighten and I think the CNC'ed thing needs a bit of WD40 as I can't turn it with my fingers.

Comment: I see, you could grip it with some pliers and turn the open lever to get better leverage.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: To me this answer looks like having to teach the correct use of quick release skewers on wheels. The Never-Ending Story, vol. 712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the same as with quick release levers for your wheels, these are essentially a nut on one side with a bolt through it, with the lever attached to the bolt on the other side.

You can damage the clamp itself or what it is clamping, such as your frame or the seat post, if you over tighten it.

To get the correct tension (from too loose), you should open the lever (red arrow) fully, and tighten the nut (blue arrow) a little and reclose the lever (red arrow). Do this until it is at the proper tension.

[image]

Alternatively, if it is too tight, you follow the same procedure as above, but loosen the nut a little instead of tightening it. An easy to remeber rule of thumb is you want the lever to just be tight enough when closed for the seat post to not move.

As a side note, some people, and me included, leave the seatclamp just a tiny bit too loose on purpose for mountain biking, BMX and street trials, just because if I fall, I would rather my seatpost swist on impact rather than maybe damaging either the seat, the post or the frame.